# How to set different dataTemplate to treeViewItems in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have TreeView (named: treeViewDiagram):

```
< TreeView  x:Name = "treeViewDiagram" Grid.Row="2"
FontFamily="/logicalTree;component/Resources/Fonts/#Oxygen"
BorderThickness="7,7,0,7" BorderBrush="#FFE9E9E9" Padding="86,0,0,0" ItemTemplateSelector="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataTemplateSelector}}" />
```

And here the three dataTamplate I have:

```
<local:CostomDataTemplateSelector x:Key="dataTemplateSelector"/>

   < DataTemplate x:Key = "BasicDataTemplate">
        < Grid Height="Auto"  MinWidth="250"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >

           <...>

        < /Grid >
    < /DataTemplate >           


    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComplexDataTemplate" >
      <Grid Height="Auto"  MinWidth="250"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">

           <...>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="RootDataTemplate" >

        <Grid Height="Auto"  MinWidth="250"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >

            <...>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Now, I want to add treeViewItems in the code and set for each treeViewItem 
different dataTemplate according my code.

(if (basic) => so: BasicDataTemplate)

(if (complex) => so: ComplexDataTemplate)

(if (root) => so: RootDataTemplate)

```
 public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (item is MyBasicData)
        {
            return element.FindResource("BasicDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        else if (item is MyComplexData)
        {
            return element.FindResource("ComplexDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        else if (item is MyRootData)
        {
            return element.FindResource("RootDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I have 3 ObservableCollection in MainWindow:

```
  private ObservableCollection< MyBasicData >  _myBasicDataCollection = new ObservableCollection< MyBasicData >();

  private ObservableCollection< MyComplexData > _myComplexDataCollection = new ObservableCollection< MyComplexData >();

  private ObservableCollection< MyRootData > _myRootDataCollection = new ObservableCollection< MyRootData >();
```

How can I do that?

Comment: see this http://tech.pro/tutorial/909/wpf-tutorial-dynamic-data-and-the-treeview

Answer (score 0):

Create *DataTemplateSelector* which iterates through every item and, based on condition, sets its DataTemplate.

```
 class TreeViewTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate BasicTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ComplexTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate RootTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is MyBasicData) return BasicTemplate;
        if (item is MyComplexData) return ComplexTemplate;
        if (item is MyRootData) return RootTemplate;
        return null;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication6">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BasicDataTemplate">

    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComplexDataTemplate">

    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RootDataTemplate">

    </DataTemplate>
    <local:TreeViewTemplateSelector x:Key="TreeViewDataTemplateSelector" BasicTemplate="{StaticResource BasicDataTemplate}"
                                    ComplexTemplate="{StaticResource ComplexDataTemplate}"
                                    RootTemplate="{StaticResource RootDataTemplate}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<TreeView ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TreeViewDataTemplateSelector}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Maximus, I already did that. I need explanation how to do that in the code behind- how set dataTemplate for each treeViewItem. It's my first time using treeView, so I need good and detailed explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Set ItemsSource to Collection comprised of all items, both Root, Basic and Complex.